# Problema con mysqli_multi_query, no se ejecuta al hacer multiconsultas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

El problema es que no sé como ejecutar la tercera multiconsulta, yo lo hice de esta manera, las dos primeras consultas si se ejecutan, pero la tercera ya no.
Aquí el código:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['place_order'])) {
require 'php/lib-generadorID.php';
    $idCarrito  = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD,  generarIDCARRITO());
    $idSesion   = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD,  generarIDSESSION());
    $idVenta    = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD,  generarIDVENTA());
    $codigoVenta= mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, codigoVenta());

    $order_details = "";
    $detalle_venta = "";

        foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {
            $sqlCart = "
                     INSERT INTO carrito (idCarrito,idCliente,idSesion,fechaHora,aux) 
                        VALUES ('$idCarrito','$idCliente','$idSesion',NOW(),'1')";

            $order_details .= "
                     INSERT INTO contenido_carrito (idCarrito,idCliente,
                            idSesion,idArticulo,codigoArticulo,codigoAlterno,
                            costo,unidades,subTotal,fechaDeRegistro,aux)
                            VALUES(
                                '$idCarrito',
                                '$idCliente',
                                '$idSesion',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_id"]) . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_codArticulo"]) . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_codAlterno"])  . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_price"])    . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_quantity"]) . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_quantity"]*$values["product_price"]) . "',
                                NOW(),
                               '1'
                              );";

            $detalle_venta .= "
                    INSERT INTO detalle_venta (idVenta, idArticulo, codigoArticulo,codigoAlterno,
                            unidades, precioDeVenta,subTotal,fechaDeRegistro, codigoVenta, aux)
                            VALUES(
                                '$idVenta',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_id"]) . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_codArticulo"]) . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_codAlterno"])  . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_quantity"])    . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_price"]) . "',
                                '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_quantity"]*$values["product_price"]) . "',
                                NOW(),
                                '$codigoVenta',
                               '1'
                              );";

                        mysqli_query($ConexionBD, $sqlCart); //primera consulta,insert into carrito

                    }
                    if (mysqli_multi_query($ConexionBD, $order_details) === true) {//segunda consulta,  insert into contenido_carrito

                        while (mysqli_more_results($ConexionBD) === true) {
                            if (mysqli_next_result($ConexionBD) === false) {
                                die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
                    }
 /*
 Aqui tengo el problema, no se llega a ejecutar esta tercera consulta, y en la base de datos no se almacena nada.
 */
                    if (mysqli_multi_query($ConexionBD, $detalle_venta) === true) {//tercera consulta, insert into detalle_venta
                        while (mysqli_more_results($ConexionBD) === true) {
                            if (mysqli_next_result($ConexionBD) === false) {
                                die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
                            }
                        }
                        unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
                        echo '<script>alert("You have successfully place an order...Thank you")</script>';
                        echo '<script>window.location.href="venta_refacciones.php"</script>';
                    } else {
                        die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
                    }

 }//end isset
 ?>
```

No sé cómo hacer esa parte, ¿me pueden orientar por favor?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64308/discussion-on-question-by-hermann-problema-con-mysqli-multi-query-no-se-ejecuta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario que hagas un `INSERT` por cada registro que desees agregar al carrito. Puedes utilizar tantos `VALUE` como necesites separando por comas cada registro:

```
INSERT INTO <tabla> (
  campo1,
  campo2,
  campo3
) VALUES (
  valor1_campo1,
  valor1_campo2,
  valor1_campo3
), (
  valor2_campo1,
  valor2_campo2,
  valor2_campo3
), ( ... ), ( ... ) ...
```

He mejorado tu código ligeramente para solucionar y mejorar un par de aspectos de él.

- Para evitar llamar a `mysqli_real_escape_string` por cada elemento de `$values` he usado [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) para recorrer los elementos y escaparlos correctamente.
- La primera consulta la he sacado fuera del bucle para que se inserte únicamente una vez, no una por cada elemento del carrito (saldrían tres registros iguales o bien si viola alguna clave primaria/única no lo sabrías porque no comprobabas si se ejecutaba correctamente o no).
- Cada campo `VALUE` lo he agregado a una matriz para que luego se puedan unir usando como pegamento la coma `,` necesaria para separar cada registro.
- He usado el mismo SQL múltiple para hacer las dos inserciones a las diferentes tablas, de modo que no se necesita la segunda llamada múltiple.

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['place_order'])) {
  require 'php/lib-generadorID.php';
  $idCarrito = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, generarIDCARRITO());
  $idSesion = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, generarIDSESSION());
  $idVenta = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, generarIDVENTA());
  $codigoVenta = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, codigoVenta());

  /* Probablemente la primera consulta haya que ejecutarla únicamente una vez */
  $sqlCart = "
    INSERT INTO carrito (
      idCarrito,
      idCliente,
      idSesion,
      fechaHora,
      aux
    ) VALUES (
      '$idCarrito',
      '$idCliente',
      '$idSesion',
      NOW(),
      '1'
    )
  ";
  if (mysqli_query($ConexionBD, $sqlCart) === false)  {
    die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
  }

  /* Función de escapado para array_walk */
  function escapar_cadena(&$cadena, $conexion) {
    $cadena = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $cadena);
  }

  /* Definimos los VALUES de cada tabla */
  $contenido_carrito = [];
  $detalle_venta = [];
  foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {
    /* Escapamos todos los valores de $values */
    array_walk($values, 'escapar_cadena', $ConexionBD);
    /* Introducimos un valor para la tabla contenido_carrito */
    array_push($contenido_carrito, "
      (
        '$idCarrito',
        '$idCliente',
        '$idSesion',
        '{$values['product_id']}',
        '{$values['product_codArticulo']}',
        '{$values['product_codAlterno']}',
        '{$values['product_price']}',
        '{$values['product_quantity']}',
        '{$values['product_quantity']}' * '{$values['product_price']}',
        NOW(),
        '1'
      )
    ");
    /* Introducimos un valor para la tabla detalle_venta */
    array_push($detalle_venta, "
      (
        '$idVenta',
        '{$values['product_id']}',
        '{$values['product_codArticulo']}',
        '{$values['product_codAlterno']}',
        '{$values['product_quantity']}',
        '{$values['product_price']}',
        '{$values['product_quantity']}' * '{$values['product_price']}',
        NOW(),
        '$codigoVenta',
        '1'
      )
    ");
  }
  /* Montamos la consulta agregando al final todos los VALUEs */
  $sql = '';
  if (count($contenido_carrito) > 0) {
    $sql .= '
      INSERT INTO contenido_carrito (
        idCarrito,
        idCliente,
        idSesion,
        idArticulo,
        codigoArticulo,
        codigoAlterno,
        costo,
        unidades,
        subTotal,
        fechaDeRegistro,
        aux
      ) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $contenido_carrito) .';';
  }
  if (count($detalle_venta) > 0) {
    $sql .= '
      INSERT INTO detalle_venta (
        idVenta,
        idArticulo,
        codigoArticulo,
        codigoAlterno,
        unidades,
        precioDeVenta,
        subTotal,
        fechaDeRegistro,
        codigoVenta,
        aux
      ) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $detalle_venta) .';';
  }
  /* De una tacada insertamos primero el carrito y luego los detalles */
  if (strlen($sql) > 0 && mysqli_multi_query($ConexionBD, $sql) === true) {
    while (mysqli_more_results($ConexionBD) === true) {
      if (mysqli_next_result($ConexionBD) === false) {
        die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
      }
    }
  } else {
    die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
  }
}//end isset
?>
```

Comment: Gracias,  me salvaste :)